# Selenium Webdriver How to switch between different Firefox windows

Tags: firefox, selenium, junit, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

In order to login to the conference as 4 different roles, for each role I wrote

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile", "default");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("link to the conference");
```

How can I switch between Firefox windows then? Windows titles are the same.
Thanks

Comment: Are you creating a new FirefoxDriver for each role? If that's the case you should just use the FirefoxDriver that corresponds to each window.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public TasksWindow OpenInWindow() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(AssertionException));
    String windowName = wait.Until<String>((d) => {
        this.windowSwitcher.Click();

        if (d.WindowHandles.Count != 2) // this means you are waiting till the number of windows equals 2 {
            return null;
        }

        return d.WindowHandles[1]; // this means you are changing to the second window (from [0] to [1])
    });

    return new TasksWindow(windowName);
}
```

This works in c#

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to navigate between your window if you want you can change it according to your needs

```
//All the window handles will be returned and u can use window handle to switch between the windows

Set<String> windows = getWebDriver().getWindowHandles();

    Iterator<String> window = windows.iterator();


    while( window.hasNext() ) {

        getWebDriver().switchTo().window( window.next() );

    }
```